# How to fill a matrix in SSRS with gradient formatting along the main diagonal?

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, gradient, conditional-formatting, reportbuilder

I have built a transition matrix and I want to be able to apply a gradient format emanating from the main diagonal outwards. Light grey to green to red as show in the picture below.

I can't seem to overlay an image on the matrix in SSRS as this is not supported in SSRS and the matrix only seems to have a fill option for the individual cells and not all the cells.

I want the result to look like one of these two options.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I worked on your query, I just created sample SSRS report with static gradient format.

Step 1 : Create below table and insert the records

```
create table report1 (id int,value int)


insert into report1 values(1,1)
insert into report1 values(2,1)
insert into report1 values(3,1)
insert into report1 values(4,1)
insert into report1 values(5,1)
insert into report1 values(6,1)
insert into report1 values(7,1)
insert into report1 values(8,1)
insert into report1 values(9,1)
insert into report1 values(10,1)
insert into report1 values(11,1)
insert into report1 values(12,1)
insert into report1 values(13,1)
insert into report1 values(14,1)
insert into report1 values(15,1)
insert into report1 values(16,1)
insert into report1 values(17,1)
insert into report1 values(18,1)
insert into report1 values(19,1)
insert into report1 values(20,1)


select * from report1
```

Step 2: Call the above table to the dataset of the SSRS report

Step 3: Create Matrix report with id as a row group with ascending order, id as a column group with descending order.

Step 4 : set below formula in fill color property of summation Textbox

```
=switch(First(Fields!id.Value,"id")+First(Fields!id.Value,"id1")<8 ,"Pink",First(Fields!id.Value,"id")+First(Fields!id.Value,"id1")<12,"LightPink",First(Fields!id.Value,"id")+First(Fields!id.Value,"id1")<16 ,"PeachPuff",First(Fields!id.Value,"id")+First(Fields!id.Value,"id1")<20 ,"#a6d3a4",First(Fields!id.Value,"id")+First(Fields!id.Value,"id1")=21,"Gray",
First(Fields!id.Value,"id")+First(Fields!id.Value,"id1")<27 ,"#a6d3a4",First(Fields!id.Value,"id")+First(Fields!id.Value,"id1")<31,"PeachPuff",First(Fields!id.Value,"id")+First(Fields!id.Value,"id1")<35 ,"LightPink",First(Fields!id.Value,"id")+First(Fields!id.Value,"id1")<41 ,"Pink")
```

Step 5: Run the report. It will show static gradient format report.

Sample Design & Output

[image: Design]

[image: Output]